# Eclipse configuration to support dual Equinox/Felix environments

Tags: eclipse, osgi, equinox, eclipse-pde, apache-felix

What are some configuration changes to make Eclipse PDE best support working with both Equinox and Felix?

Here's an example problem I'm currently having. I can run my application ok via the Eclipse OSGi Framework launcher. Similarly, there are no compilation problems in PDE. However, when running in Felix I will get NoClassDefFoundErrors:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/DOMException
```

My understanding is it's my Eclipse setup that is at fault here; org.w3c.dom is not a 'default' OSGi package and shouldn't be loaded when I run it in Eclipse. Similarly, the import in my code for org.w3c.dom.DOMException should be an error.

I know how to fix this for Felix: declare an Import-Package. But that's not my question. My question is how to force Eclipse PDE to take on a closer configuration to Felix... basically to make it stricter in loading packages?

Answer (score 1):

I think Equinox *does* behave like Felix, if you run it stand alone. It's more of an Eclipse legacy thing than an Equinox thing, as stated on [osgi.org](http://wiki.osgi.org/wiki/Why_does_Eclipse_find_javax.swing_but_not_Felix?).

As far as I know, there isn't any way to override the boot delegation from Eclipse, but I'd love to be proven wrong, as I've faced this problem often.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll edit the question to concentrate on the Eclipse launcher and PDE.

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing a server application I recommend to not use the PDE at all. I am using maven and the maven bundle plugin to develop my bundles. Then I deploy on Apache karaf. Debugging also is quite simple by using the karaf dev:watch command and remote debugging. I never really missed the PDE features and they never worked well with my maven build.

Comment: Is that Maven with bnd or are you managing the manifest yourself? My understanding is that if you're doing the latter that's *two* places you have to specify dependencies.

Comment: I use the maven bundle plugin from felix which uses bnd internally. So there is only one place to specify dependencies. Bnd also detects most dependencies automatically. So most times there is not much to do.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like that launcher is setting bootdelegation to legacy mode. See the following page on the OSGi Wiki: http://wiki.osgi.org/wiki/Why_does_Eclipse_find_javax.swing_but_not_Felix%3F

Comment: Here's the options that are sent :   -Declipse.ignoreApp=true -Dosgi.noShutdown=true -Dosgi.dev -Dosgi.debug=/home/gravelld/eclipse-workspaces/bliss/com.elsten.bliss.bundle/.options -Declipse.log.level=ALL -Dbliss.obr.updaterepository=file:/home/gravelld/eclipse-workspaces/bliss/com.elsten.bliss.installer/release/bliss-bundle/repository.xml -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /opt/eclipse-indigo/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main . So I don't see anything there. Also, that doesn't explain why the PDE doesn't catch it at compile time.